# including if null in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i have to include null for the below code? and why its necessary to use null?

```js
$("a").each(function() {
    if (($(this).attr("href").indexOf(".PDF") > 1) || ($(this).attr("href").indexOf(".pdf") > 1)) {
          var url = $(this).attr("href");
          $(this).attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','Document'," + "'" + url + "'" + "])");
    }
}); // to find the pdf links in a website
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does "include null" mean? Do you mean you need to check `$(this).attr("href")` for null?

Comment: Note can avoid the `||` condition by changing case of the string. `if ($(this).attr("href").toUpperCase().indexOf(".PDF") > 1)` ....Beyond that ... no idea what you are asking

Comment: yes,this script is blocking the ajax links too. so i need to know whether using the null condition would solve this issue?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to make sure that you only target links that have an  `href` that ends with some case variation of `.pdf`. You don't need to test for `null` here at all as long as you just correctly search for the links that match your criteria.

This can be done much more simply than you are doing:

```js
var _gaq = [];

// Instead of looping over all the links and then checking each to see if it is a link you want,
// just get the links that you need to work with in the first place. Any links that don't match
// the criteria will simply be skipped.
// The "$=" means "ends-with and the "i" in the attribute selector indicates that 
// it is a case-insensitive search.
$("a[href$='.pdf' i]").each(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    
    console.log(url); // <-- Just for demonstration to prove that only the right links were found
    
    // Don't set up inline event handlers, use modern standards
    $(this).on("click", function(event){
    
      console.clear();
      event.preventDefault(); // <-- This is just for this demonstration only
      
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','Document', url]);
      console.log(_gaq);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="something.pdf">something.pdf</a>
<a href="something.html">something.html</a>
<a href="something.pDf">something.pDf</a>
<a href="something.jpg">something.jpg</a>
<a href="something.Pdf">something.Pdf</a>
```